# How to make "php" link to php5.5 on Mac (already created symlink on /usr/local/bin/php)?

Tags: php, macos, command-line, homebrew, symlink

I installed php version 5.5 through homebrew and I now want php on the command line to refer to this new version. In /usr/local/bin I ran ls -l and saw this line:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myself  admin   37 Aug 26 13:06 php -> /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.1/bin/php
```

but `php -v` tells me that I have PHP 5.3.15

Does anybody know what I need to do to have this point to version 5.5.x?

==UPDATE==
It turned out the symlink was broken somehow, so I made brew fix it and now it works like a charm!

Excuse me for the confusion!

Comment: In the future, change your 'updates' to an answer, so that this gets off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the symlink was broken somehow, so I made brew fix it and now it works like a charm!

Excuse me for the confusion!